# Portable data annotations does not work in UWP project

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I use [portable data annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.DataAnnotations/) in Xamarin forms, When I deploy UWP project and run it, I catch `MissingManifestResourceException` (*exceptions details added below*) while I added portable data annotations in PCL project and UWP project both.

I try [Net46-Portable.DataAnnotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Net46-Portable.DataAnnotations/)
 and [Portable-Strong.DataAnnotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable-Strong.DataAnnotations/) but does not work again.

Where is my wrong?

- My UWP project Target version Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)
- My UWP project Min version Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586)
- My mobile I test it is Windows phone 10 Anniversary Edition.
- Xamarin forms version is [2.3.4.171-pre1](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases/tag/beta-2.3.4-pre1)

  ```
  System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException occurred
    HResult=-2146233038
    Message=Unable to load resources for resource file "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Resources.DataAnnotationsResources" in package "ResaDoctorApp".
    Source=mscorlib
    StackTrace:
         at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
         at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Resources.DataAnnotationsResources.get_EmailAddressAttribute_Invalid()
         at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute..ctor()
         at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateCaInstance(RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimePropertyInfo property, RuntimeType caType)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Attribute.InternalGetCustomAttributes(PropertyInfo element, Type type, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
         at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
         at AutoMapper.Configuration.MappingExpression`2.Configure(IProfileConfiguration profile, TypeMap typeMap)
         at AutoMapper.Profile.BuildTypeMap(TypeMapRegistry typeMapRegistry, ITypeMapConfiguration config)
         at AutoMapper.Profile.AutoMapper.IProfileConfiguration.Register(TypeMapRegistry typeMapRegistry)
         at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Seal(IConfiguration configuration)
         at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression, IEnumerable`1 mappers)
         at AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(Action`1 config)
         at DoctorApp.Models.Doctor.FillFromFather(DoctorPreview preview)
    InnerException:
  ```

Comment: DataAnnotations is an excellent library providing validation support in .NET. However, it is not implemented on the  [Windows Phone platforms](https://github.com/ryanhorath/PortableDataAnnotations)(Silverlight and WinRT). When creating a PCL using those platforms, DataAnnotations will be unavailable

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Why doesn't the [System.ComponentModel.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations) package support portable apps?